# enabling flashlight in Device using Vuforia version 10.8 and unity version 2020.3.33f

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

I have used the below code for enabling the device flashlight using toggle button in unity and my device is compatible with vuforia. For the above code i keep on getting this error

Assets\TextMesh Pro\FlashlightController.cs(10,22): error CS0117: 'CameraDevice' does not contain a definition for 'Instance'
is there a way to resolve this issue

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class FlashlightController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isFlashlightOn = false;

    void Start()
    {
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(false); // Ensure flashlight is initially off
    }

    public void ToggleFlashlight()
    {
        isFlashlightOn = !isFlashlightOn;

        if (isFlashlightOn)
            CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(true); // Turn on the flashlight
        else
            CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(false); // Turn off the flashlight
        }
    }
```